# Where does the energy go in a rocket when no work is done?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, energy-conservation, work, rocket-science

While playing Kerbal Space Program, I wondered where my chemical energy would go when fired at 90° to the motion. It would do no work on the rocket, but all that energy has to go somewhere, right? Anyway, my question is, where does the energy go?

Comment: _"It would do no work on the rocket"_ What makes you think that?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit A force $\mathbf F$ applied orthogonal to the velocity $\mathbf v$ performs no power $P=\mathbf F·\mathbf v$ and therefore no work, and it does not affect the kinetic energy of the particle.

Comment: @EmilioPisanty: Um if I apply a sideways force to an upwards moving object does it not begin to go diagonally?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Yes. However, if the impulse is extended (i.e. the trajectory changes appreciably while you're still thrusting) then a thrust component is against the initial velocity so that component of $\mathbf v$ is reduced and $||\mathbf v||$ stays constant. For an infinitesimal impulse, the change in the cross component of the velocity is also infinitesimal and it does not change the total velocity (which is quadratic in the change). I'm not sure why these comments are getting upvoted - this is an easy mistake to make but it's mechanics 101 material.

Comment: I'm basically quoting _my_ mechanics 101 material. I don't see how applying additional force to a body can result in no net velocity increase. That seems ridiculous to me. Just because I push a body sideways doesn't mean it stops going upwards so fast. I'm adding to the velocity, not simply redistributing its component vectors.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Let's say that the rocket is traveling in the $y$-direction at some velocity $v$, which may or may not be non-zero. A force - in this case, thrust provided by the engine - is applied perpendicular to the direction of motion, in the $x$-direction. This force produces an acceleration, which causes the rocket to move. Therefore, the force is *not* applied at a 90 degree angle to the motion of the rocket, and a non-zero amount of work is done.

**Case 1: Force applied continuously in the $x$-direction**

Here's how the angle between the motion and the applied force changes over time:

[image]

<sup>As [alexgotsis noted](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/213280/56299) (answer since deleted), the force will give the rocket angular momentum if the engine does not fire precisely against the center of mass of the rocket. I really should have drawn the picture better.</sup>

Let's do some math.

The initial velocity can be broken up into components $v_{x_0}$ and $v_{y_0}$. Given that there is zero force applied in the $y$-direction, we can conclude that $v_x=v_{x_0}$ for all times $t$.

Assuming a constant force $F=F_x$, we have some acceleration, $a=a_x$. We can calculate the velocity, $v_x$, at any time $t$ by using
$$v_{x_f}=v_{x_0}+a_xt$$
The angle between the direction of motion and the force is $90+\theta$. Here,
$$\theta=\tan^{-1}\left(\frac{v_y}{v_x}\right)=\tan^{-1}\left(\frac{v_y}{v_{x_0}+a_xt}\right)$$
The work done at any given time is
$$W=\int F\cdot ds\cos(90+\theta)=\int F\cdot ds\cos\left(90+\tan^{-1}\left(\frac{v_y}{v_{x_0}+a_xt}\right)\right)$$
To find $ds$, you need to figure out how far the rocket has traveled.

**Case 2: Force applied continuously at some angle to the direction of motion of the rocket.**

This all holds if the rocket is continuously fired in the $x$-direction. If it is fired *at some angle to the rocket's motion at any given time*, then you have different motion:

[image]

<sup>Here, the force happens to be applied at an angle near 90 degrees, but not quite.</sup>

The motion now is more complex, because the acceleration vector is dependent on $\theta$.

So where does the energy go? Into the rocket and its exhaust, as kinetic energy.

**Case 3: Force applied continuously perpendicular to the direction of motion of the rocket**

What if we fix the engine so it always thrusts perpendicular the direction of the rocket's motion? We get uniform circular motion:

[image]

In this case, all the energy goes into the exhaust of the rocket. The rocket itself maintains uniform kinetic energy, so long as it has uniform speed. This is the case I think you were talking about.

Comment: *"In all cases where a force is applied perpendicular to the object's motion and no net work is done, there is a second force countering it."* Simply isn't true. Consider an object in a circular orbit. The thing is that in the case you drew the force is only perpendicular at the beginning of the interval depicted.

Comment: @dmckee In a rotating reference frame, doesn't the centrifugal force arises to balance out the opposing force? Or is that not a valid counterargument because it's a fictitious force?

Comment: I agree with dmckee. Consider a rocket in deep space keeping a circular path using its engine.

Comment: The centrifugal **pseudo**force isn't a force. It's a mathematical artifact of using a non-inertial frame of reference. It is certainly true that in a rotating frame the orbit has constant KE and that can be attributed to the canceling of the real force and the pseudoforce, but it is also true in an inertial frame that the KE is constant, so still zero work and no pseudoforce to blame it on.

Comment: @dmckee Okay, I understand the argument. Sentence removed.

Comment: Your diagram still has the assumption that the direction of thrust remains constant while the rocket's path bends. That may or may not be what the OP intended.

Comment: Well, since it's accepted, it is apparently what OP intended. Still, it'd be interesting to explore what happens with the always perpendicular interpretation.

Comment: @dmckee I'm working on it.

Comment: I don't think this answer gets to the point; after all, you could continuously rotate the rocket while firing to mantain 90°.

Comment: Thank you for the great answer, I meant the second case, but thanks for all your help.

Comment: `The rocket itself maintains uniform kinetic energy, so long as it has uniform velocity` -- Should be careful with terminology here.  In the final case (circular motion), the rocket's *speed* (scalar) is constant but its *velocity* (vector) is continuously changing.  You might use *"...its velocity has constant magnitude"*, etc.

Answer (score 10):

Very little of the energy from a rocket engine *ever* goes to the kinetic energy of the rocket. The only way you get perfect conversion to KE of the rocket is when the propellant is directed in the opposite direction of motion and when the ejection velocity is exactly equal to the speed of the rocket. In that case, the propellant winds up containing 0 kinetic energy, thus all the kinetic energy liberated in the process goes into the rocket.

If the propellant is fired perpendicular to the direction of motion, then the rocket sees 0 change in its own kinetic energy. For the record, this only applies to one frame of reference (probably that of the nearby planet).

In this scenario that you have described, **all of the change in kinetic energy** liberated by the rocket engine **goes into the propellant**.

Of course, the total energy of the *reaction* is much more, and a great deal of that goes to heat.

Comment: For some reason, this makes it sound like the most efficient rocket would start with low exhaust velocity, increasing as the rocket increased its own velocity. Perhaps it's most energy-efficient, but not exhaust-mass-efficient?

Comment: @DanielGriscom: Yes, that's right.  That's the big problem with rockets, esp. for liftoff.  Space elevators, or even railgun-style accelerators, are much more energy-efficient ways of getting a payload to orbit or at least off the ground.

Comment: @DanielGriscom At any given time there is always an inertial reference frame where the rocket has instant velocity 0.

Comment: There's a reason you do not do rocket calculation in energy. They get ugly fast.

Comment: As a way of making the point that `the energy goes into the propellant` less counterintuitive, consider a ship going along the $x$ axis with velocity $v_x$, and firing the rocket along $y$ with exhaust velocity $v_y$. Then the kinetic energy of the exhausted propellant (I think that'd be the right term) is $\propto \mathbf v^2=v_x^2+v_y^2$, i.e. the exact sum of the initial kinetic energy from the ship's motion plus the kinetic energy gained from the chemical reaction. If the exhaust is not orthogonal to the orbit, that's no longer true.

Answer (score 0):

If a train is moving along the tracks at 60 mph and there's a crosswind at 30 mph the crosswind, in fact, does not do any work on the train. That's because the train's motion is **constrained** by the rails so that it **cannot** move in the direction that the wind is pushing it. If you remove the constraint its motion **will change** because the wind is doing work on it. That's why, for example, if you row a boat straight across a river you end up downstream from where you started: the current moved you downstream. In order to end up directly across from where you started you have to aim the boat upstream, to compensate for the current. Either way, the current is doing work on the boat. Same thing for your rocket.